AttributeError: 'Kml' object has no attribute 'style'
I am learning how to use simplekml and i am having a hard time adding a particular icon on a point.
this is my code:
import simplekml
points_kml = simplekml.Kml()
points_kml.newpoint(name="Kirstenbosch", coords=[(18.432314,-33.988862)])
points_kml.style.iconstyle.icon.href = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/ltblu-circle.png'
points_kml.save("botanicalgarden.kml")

and this is what i receive in return:
  File c:\users\marcelo\downloads\untitled0.py:4
    points_kml.style.iconstyle.icon.href = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/ltblu-circle.png'

AttributeError: 'Kml' object has no attribute 'style'

I double checked the documentation and the icon link but everything is exactly how it shows in the documentation...
I just wanted a kml file with a single point and a particular icon.

The error is telling you what you need to know. The Kml object has no style on it.
Looking at these docs you might be trying to reference a point? You're creating one but you never save it to anything. An example from those docs
pnt = kml.newpoint(name="Kirstenbosch", description="A botanical Garden",
                   coords=[(18.432314,-33.988862)])  # lon, lat optional height

Some code from those docs touching the style from a point
pnt.style.iconstyle.icon.href = None

